# 配列の中の合計を計算したい

Tags: swift, xcode

### swift

```
import UIKit
import CoreMotion

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var Myaccelx: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var accelxaddition: UILabel!


let motionManager: CMMotionManager = CMMotionManager()
var timer:NSTimer = NSTimer()
var countArray = [String]() //配列
var bele = 20
var kazu = 0
var j = 0
var num = 0


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    // Initialize MotionManager
    motionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 0.05 // 20Hz

    // Start motion data acquisition
    motionManager.startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue( NSOperationQueue.currentQueue(), withHandler:{
        deviceManager, error in
        var accel: CMAcceleration = deviceManager.userAcceleration

        self.countArray.append("\(accel.x)")

        if self.countArray.count >= self.bele {
            self.countArray.removeAtIndex(0)
        }

        self.Myaccelx.text = ("\(self.countArray)")

        self.timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "Count", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    })
}


func Count(){



}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
 }


}
```

上記のプログラムですが、Countの処理のところで配列の中の合計を計算したいです。
1秒に２０回（0.05Hz）の加速度の計算ができるので、１秒ごとに合計値を求める処理を行いたいです。
どのようにかけばよろしいでしょうか。

Answer (score 2):

Swiftは、配列（`Array`）について、`map`と`reduce`という関数が用意されています。
（`filter`という関数もありますが、ここでは割愛）

```
let floatArray: [Double] = [1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5]

let mapResult: [Double] = floatArray.map({(a: Double) -> Double in
    a * 2.0
})

// output: [2, 2.2, 2.4, 2.6, 2.8, 3]

let reduceResult: Double = floatArray.reduce(0.0, combine: {
    (a: Double, b: Double) -> Double in
    a + b
})

// output: 7.5
```

上のサンプルコードについて、`map`関数は、配列の全要素に`2.0`を乗算しています。
`reduce`関数は、前回までの結果に要素の値を加算しており、全体として、全要素の加算を行っています。
両関数について、日本語の情報をネットで多数見つけることができますから、それらで勉強してください。

ご質問に対しては、`reduce`関数が役に立つでしょう。なので、計算をする目的があるのに、わざわざ実数（Double、Floatなど）を文字列に変換するのは、無駄な処理ということができると思います。